# jade condition failed in my case

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to hide the p base on the variable of hide_it. so in my controller hide_it set to true

```
res.locals.hide_it = true;
console.log(res.locals.hide_it) // working, returned true
```

but it wasn't working when I do in jade

```
-if(!hide_it)
 p hello
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jade indentation is "2 spaces"

you should use

```
if !hide_it
  p hello
```

it would also work with the "-" prefix (javascript mode) but it is not advised in this case where the standard Jade `if` notation can work.

you can test your template in the online demo - http://jade-lang.com/demo/

Comment: Thanks your code worked! `p(style='display:(hide === true ? "none" : "block"')` is this do able?

Comment: p(style='display:'+((hide===true)?'none':'block')) ; the expression after 'style=' should be javascript